# How to get a post meta value and pass that to update_option when a post is created or updated?

Tags: save-post, post-meta, options

When a user publishes or updates a post I want to get a post meta value from that post itself. Then I want to use update_option() to pass that value into the get_option() name.

I've been trying multiple things and I know this works, but it seems the issue I am having is this happening during the save_post action? If I remove the action everything works fine. I've tried other action points but still nothing has worked.

I'm kind of guessing that at the time these actions run is before the post_meta data is saved so I can get that value in time to pass to the update_option(); Is this true?

How should I go about this? - Thanks.

Comment: Or the issue is detecting the id of the post itself so I can get the post meta from the post being created after it's saved, then passing that into update_option. ?

Comment: When the user publishes the post, will the meta value you want be submitted? If so, using the `save_post` hook, the meta value will be available in the $_POST variable and you can use update_option to save it to the `options` table.

Comment: @AncientRo thanks. Yes and this makes sense. I've looked around for about an hour because I'm not familiar with the global $_POST. Do you know how I can inspect this on the save_post action or how to access my saved array fields submitted? I tried just using $_POST['my-field'] but nothing happened. But I don't know what the data in there looks like.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context, please? What post type are you using, a custom post type or a native one? How did you add the meta post fields? If you added them through code, can you post a snipped of your html code?

Comment: @AncientRo thanks. Sure. In sentence form, I'm trying to allow my user to create their site layout from a post type itself. So my post type is actually "post-type-layout". When a user creates a layout in that post type I want to store the post id from that post and add it into a get_option(). Then when the site determines which layout to load I will simply get the post id from the get_option(). Then I will know which post id to get the post meta from for the layout options created in that post-type-layout post. Hope that makes sense. Sounds a bit tongue twister on words.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of code I've been playing with @ https://shrtm.nu/EqTp - Note: I left in some of the old code so you can see what I was trying. Hopefully that helps explain. Also my $data::get() function is just a wrapper for the get_option and get_post_meta depending on the arg passed into it. They both work the same.

Comment: And here is a screenshot of my fields on that post-type-layout @ https://shrtm.nu/9a6c. It is submitted via my theme's framework which is the Codestar Framework @ http://codestarframework.com/ But this is a modified and newer version of the framework. The docs for the most part concept is the same. Standard metabox submission I believe.

Comment: Ultimately I'm trying to allow custom post type layouts but I'm aiming to avoid the way I've seen others do it by gather all the data from the published posts in the post type layouts post type, then making a decision off of that data. I think it's not needed because of all the extra data pulled in that isn't being used to make a decision of which layout to load. So I'm trying to pass the post id of the post itself into get option then the use that stored post id to know which post_meta to get for the layout to be loaded.

Comment: Lastly, since I hit this bump in the road I'm now considering maybe storing that data in a file and searching that file instead for the data needed. Sorry to be a little longer on the comments. Just wanted to be thorough and make sure if you come back around you have everything you need to actually help, haha. Instead of asking me to provide something else or an example, etc. Don't want to waste your time. Thanks! Appreciate you!

Comment: It's not a problem with the number of comments, it's actually a very good thing to give as much info as possible, it makes things easier to understand and it's appreciated. For future reference, it is best to include all the extra info in the original post so that other people who read the thread can see it better at once and so that you have unlimited space. I am reading through your comments and trying to understand the functionality and I have one first question: how does the site determine which layout to load?

Comment: Also, about your last point, I would not advise using a file to store data. A database is especially built for that function and it is much better from the point of view of performance. You also want to have consistency with how the WP platform works.

Comment: It seems from your comments that you are trying to get the id of the submitted post. But you already have that in your code, from `global $post` and `$post->id`. Are you trying to retrieve other value from the submitted post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56330/discussion-between-noahj-champion-and-ancientro).